# How many variations of a term can be used before Google punishes your site?

Tags: seo, google

I have a new client with a huge inventory of antique items.  My client has each item named properly on the website, however, each item has many common variations of each name.  Often times the most popular search term is not the proper (official) name.  I had the thought of creating a page for each variant of the name, which would create a page that looked like

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Product One Name A</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Product One Name A</h1>
<p>Product One Name A blah, blah, blah</p>
<h2>Product One Name A is also known as</h2>
<ul>
<li><a href=ProductOneNameB/>Product One Name B</a></li>
<li><a href=ProductOneNameC/>Product One Name C</a></li>
<li><a href=ProductOneNameD/>Product One Name D</a></li>
<li><a href=ProductOneNameE/>Product One Name E</a></li>
<li><a href=ProductOneNameF/>Product One Name F</a></li>
</ul>
</body></html>
```

I would then create the ProductOneNameB page, which would have the names changed a bit, but it would have the same description, structure and images.

My hope is that I can rank high for each of the keywords.  At the moment, the client is ranking high for the proper names, but not the variations.

My question is, will Google consider this gaming the system, and punish me in the rankings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's creating low quality content. It's the same thing over and over again. No one is going to link to it so it will rank poorly. Create enough of it and the site may run afoul of the "panda" algorithm and the whole site may suffer for it.

A better plan might be to put some of the alternative terminology on the current product page and link to that same page with those alternative terms in the anchor text.

Comment: you could add sentences like "also known as..." or "often confused with ..."

Comment: Exactly. It is an excellent way to improve the content of the page and get those keywords in the content at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

Essentially the problem is that you need to create more *interesting* content. I understand the desire for people to want the top search results for terms relating to their sites, however it is feckless to make people see something they don't desire, want, or need.

Answer (score 0):

The quantity you can produce while flying under the radar likely depends heavily on your niche, and the authority of the site as a whole. I'd classify it as a high risk tactic and wouldn't recommend it for any site you want to rank long term.

I'd suggest writing product descriptions that include the related terms or even have a resource section gives information about each products, various uses, comparisons, alternative names etc. it's a safer route and with the help of some copy writers can be done fairly quickly and affordably.